# How to get files name with spark sc.textFile?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading a directory of files using the following code:

```
val data = sc.textFile("/mySource/dir1/*")
```

now my  `data` rdd contains all rows of all files in the directory (right?)

I want now to add a column to each row with the source files name, how can I do that?

The other options I tried is using wholeTextFile but I keep getting out of memory exceptions.
5 servers 24 cores 24 GB (executor-core 5 executor-memory 5G)
any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get filenames if you use the code snippet above. However, you can get filenames only by doing `sc.wholeTextFiles("/path/to/dir").keys`. But I don't think your error is caused by using wholeTextFile vs. textFile - it's caused by what you do with the data after that. You should post your other code.

Comment: I don't have any other code, just wholeTextFile and count()

Comment: 1. how many files are in the directory; 2. did you try your code on a local machine first 3. how do you run spark

Comment: About 1222 files in directories

Comment: What do you mean locally, the files are on hdfs

Comment: I use spark-shell --master yarn-client --executor-core 5 --executor-memory 5G

Comment: I would try `spark-shell --master local[5]` (spark on local machine)  and then something like  `sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///home/kris/spark/myscripts").count`  (`file:///...` allows you to do it on local dir). I mean, isolate that your code is correct on a smaller instance. Sometimes a typo can compile but do unintended things. E.g. you keep talking about `wholeTextFile` but it is `wholeTextFiles`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this code. I have tested it with Spark 1.4 and 1.5.

It gets the file name from the `inputSplit` and adds it to each line using the `iterator` using the `mapPartitionsWithInputSplit` of the `NewHadoopRDD`

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.{FileSplit, TextInputFormat}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.{NewHadoopRDD}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local"))

val fc = classOf[TextInputFormat]
val kc = classOf[LongWritable]
val vc = classOf[Text]

val path :String = "file:///home/user/test"
val text = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, fc ,kc, vc, sc.hadoopConfiguration)

val linesWithFileNames = text.asInstanceOf[NewHadoopRDD[LongWritable, Text]]
           .mapPartitionsWithInputSplit((inputSplit, iterator) => {
  val file = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit]
  iterator.map(tup => (file.getPath, tup._2))
  }
)

linesWithFileNames.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty late to answer this question but I found an easy way to do what you were looking for:

- Step 0: `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`
- Step 1: createDataFrame using the RDD as usual. Let's say df
- Step 2: Use `input_file_name()`

```
df.withColumn("INPUT_FILE", F.input_file_name())
```

This will add a column to your `DataFrame` with source file name.